# Почему поступает пустой запрос? (python + qiwi)

Tags: python, qiwi

```
def form_oplata(api_access_token,sum, user_id):
    s = requests.Session()
    s.headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
    s.headers['authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + api_access_token
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Android v3.2.0 MKT'
    s.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    parameters = {
        "amountInteger": sum,
        "currency":'643',
        "extra":{
                  "comment": user_id
              }
    }

    h = s.get(f'https://qiwi.com/payment/form/99?', params = parameters)

    return h
```

https://qiwi.com/payment/form/99?amountInteger=99&currency=643&extra=comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import requests

def createQiwiPayForm(sum: float, userID: int):
    params = {
        "amount": sum,
        "extra['comment']": userID,
        "currency": 643,
        "extra['account']": 79991112233
    }

    h = requests.get("https://qiwi.com/payment/form/99?", params=params)

    return h


print(createQiwiPayForm(193, 1488228).url)
```

Такую ссылку напечатает:

https://qiwi.com/payment/form/99?amount=193&extra%5B%27comment%27%5D=1488228&currency=643&extra%5B%27account%27%5D=79991112233

Comment: https://developer.qiwi.com/ru/qiwi-wallet-personal/#autocomplete

Comment: переписал, надо просто ключ с extra как в документации указывать, то есть extra['comment']

Comment: Спасибо, большое. Извините не могу ставить вам лайки..